# Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms

I have the following HTML but i get the the exception. How to fix it ?

> Parser Error: Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected
>   at column 48 in
>   [!(editForm.controls.field_item_exportExpression_{{i}}?.dirty &&
>   editForm.controls.field_item_exportExpression_{{i}}?.invalid)]

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="form-control-label" for="field_exportExpression">exportExpression</label>
  <input class="form-control" type="text" id="field_item_exportExpression_{{i}}" name="item_exportExpression_{{i}}" [(ngModel)]="datatype.items[i].exportExpression" required>
  <div [hidden]="!(editForm.controls.field_item_exportExpression_{{i}}?.dirty && editForm.controls.field_item_exportExpression_{{i}}?.invalid)">
   <small class="form-text text-danger" [hidden]="!editForm.controls.field_item_exportExpression_{{i}}?.errors?.required" dpTranslate="dataconfiguration.validation.required"> This field is
                            required. </small>
 </div>
</div>
```

The following is not working. Saying unwanted token `[` found.

```
[hidden]="!editForm.controls.['item_exportExpression_' + i]?.errors?.required
```

The following is not complaining about `[` but complaining `Cannot read property '0' of undefined`

```
 [hidden]="!editForm.controls.item_exportExpression_[ i]?.errors?.required
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parser Error: Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40203279/parser-error-got-interpolation-where-expression-was-expected)

Comment: @jonrsharpe i saw that post already and he has $index which the answer says {{$index}} . my case i have i and i put in {{i}} dosent work.

Comment: @jonrsharpe : i am one week old angular person and i dont care  at all about rep

Comment: Then put that research in the question - *"I read X and tried Y but Z happened"*. Otherwise, as above, people end up telling you things you already know. Again, this is something you should already be aware of (like the fact that serially downvoting is against the rules).

Comment: Perhaps you can simplify the problem by moving the hidden="code" into your Component Class, and just have a function [hidden]="shouldHide()" that way everything is easier

Comment: @BrianOgden : Could you please recommend in any tutorial of what you suggested. Since i am new to angular i am not quite able to follow you properly

Comment: @SaurabhKumar you have many tutorials that you could follow, get a subscription to Pluralsight for a month or two for example and you will find great Angular2 tutorials, for example John Papa instructs a nice one

Comment: You have a syntax error when you got the unwanted token found error.  Remove the period before the open square bracket.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

template

```
<div [hidden]="!checkIfInvalid(i, 'item_exportExpression_')">
                            <small class="form-text text-danger" [hidden]="isRequiredError(i, 'item_exportExpression_')" dpTranslate="dataconfiguration.validation.required"> This field is
                                required. </small>
    </div>
```

component

```
checkIfInvalid( index: number, field: string ): boolean {
        const control = this.getControl( index, field );
        if ( control && control.dirty && !control.valid ) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    isRequiredError( index: number, field?: string ): boolean {
        const control = this.getControl( index, field );
        if ( control && control.getError( "required" ) ) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: this.getControl means

Comment: how to declare control in component

Answer (score 87):

`{{}}` **never** goes together with `[prop]="..."` or `(event)="..."`

```
<small class="form-text text-danger" 
       [hidden]="!editForm.controls.['field_item_exportExpression_' + i]?.errors?.required" dpTranslate="dataconfiguration.validation.required"> This field is
                        required. 
</small>
```

Answer (score 54):

There are 4 types of bindings:

- **Property binding** i.e. `[]` required to evaluate values
- **Model binding** i.e. `[()]` required nothing special
- **Interpolation binding** i.e. `{{}}` could be used with general attributes
- **Event binding** i.e. `()` worked great with functions

To answer your question, something like this worked for us:

```
<input type="checkbox" [id]="['model-'+i]" [(ngModel)]="model" name="model-{{i}}" (change)="changeHandler($event)" />
```

Comment: The 'id' is bound to an array... is there any difference:`[id]="['model-'+i]"` vs `[id]="'model-'+i"`?

Comment: @istibekesi If you implement both, does it make any difference as such? I have not worked on Angular since long, so not sure about it.

Comment: There is no difference in the result, since `['anything'].toString() === 'anything'`... I was just wondering if is there any reason/practice to use this array syntax? 
(Most probably, there isn't.)

Answer (score 6):

Use like this instead of interpolation

```
  <button class="btn btn-primary" title="Edit" (click)="showEditModal(record.id)"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></button>
```