# How to pass value in angular 2 selector using variable?

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to pass value to selector of angular like below. What is different in this question is that I am passing the variables to selector properties of child component.

```
              <app-jform 
                  [modulename]="'({{modulename}})'"
                  [tabpgrpid]="'({{tabpgrpid}})'"
                   [tabgrpname]="'({{tabgrpname}})'"
                 [usertabgrpname]="'({{usertabgrpname}})'"
                  [moduleid]="'({{moduleid}})'"
                [templateid]="'({{templateid}})'">
             </app-jform>
```

here modulename, tabgrpid, tabgrpname etc. are variables defined and assigned in component. I am getting the following error while doing this.

```
                 Parser Error: Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was 
                 expected at column 1 in ['{{modulename}}'] in 
               ng:///AppModule/ViewBaseComponent.html@65:3 ("

                   <app-jform 
            [ERROR ->][modulename]="'{{modulename}}'"
           [tabpgrpid]="'{{tabpgrpid}}'"
          [tabgrpname]="'{{tabgrpname}}'"
            "): ng:///AppModule/ViewBaseComponent.html@65:3
```

how to pass this variables to properties of selector?

Comment: Change like this,

`<app-jform 
                  [modulename]="modulename"
                  [tabpgrpid]="tabpgrpid"
                   [tabgrpname]="tabgrpname"
                 [usertabgrpname]="usertabgrpname"
                  [moduleid]="moduleid"
                [templateid]="templateid">
             </app-jform> `

Comment: First little bit try by your self or googling and then post question. This is basic

Comment: Dup of https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bangular%5D+Got+interpolation

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42456459/got-interpolation-where-expression-was-expected)

Comment: I tried the solution from above questions but couldn't use that. Either I am getting errors or no data is getting passed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pass without the annotation

```
<app-jform  [modulename]="modulename"
            [tabpgrpid]="tabpgrpid"
            [tabgrpname]="tabgrpname"
            [usertabgrpname]="usertabgrpname"
            [moduleid]="moduleid"
            [templateid]="templateid">
 </app-jform>
```

Comment: I am getting this error after trying like this.
Parser Error: Unexpected token 'Lexer Error: Unterminated quote at column 11 in expression [modulename']' at column 12 in [modulename'] in ng:///AppModule/ViewBaseComponent.html@57:12 ("


<app-jform  [ERROR ->][modulename]="modulename'"
            [tabpgrpid]="tabpgrpid"
            [tabgrpname]="tabgrpname"

Comment: there was extra single quote, try it now

Comment: I removed the single quotes, Now there is no parsing errors but data is not getting assigned now. its saying undefined in component.

Comment: when I use this <p> {{modulename}} {{tabpgrpid}} {{tabgrpname}} {{usertabgrpname}} </p> just above the selector I have all values printed...also if I assign some hardcoded values, the parameters of selctors are working.

Comment: I am not getting any errors now but the value of property like modulename is undefined at ngonit function.

Comment: What happened,  is modulename variable was not ready and even it was getting assigned .I just Put the ngif condition and then printed the same thing. and problem solved.