# Create unique variable name inside *ngFor

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to make a table that, when you click a button, it needs to display the row directly beneath it.

I have had a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42456459/got-interpolation-where-expression-was-expected) post, but I could not find an answer from it.

When I have it like below, it works, but the problem is, it displays all other hidden rows since they all share the same `collapse variable`.

This is the working example, but not 100% correct:

```
<table>
<thead>
  <th>Path out of this queue</th>
  <th *ngFor="let role of roles">{{role.RoleName}}</th>>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let queue of workQueues; let i = index">
    <tr>
      <td><button (click)="collapse=!collapse">{{queue.WorkQueueName}}</button></td>
      <td *ngFor="let role of roles">
        <input type="checkbox" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngIf="collapse">
      Yay...
    </tr>
  </ng-container>
</tbody>
```

I thought I would be able to make the `collapse variable` unique, by appending the `i`, which is the `index`, to it, but then I get the following error:

> Parser Error: Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected

Here is my attempt:

```
<table>
<thead>
  <th>Path out of this queue</th>
  <th *ngFor="let role of roles">{{role.RoleName}}</th>>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let queue of workQueues; let i = index">
    <tr>
      <td><button (click)="{{collapse+i}}={{!collapse+i}}">{{queue.WorkQueueName}}</button></td>
      <td *ngFor="let role of roles">
        <input type="checkbox" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngIf="{{collapse+i}}">
      Yay...
    </tr>
  </ng-container>
</tbody>
```

Specifically, in my `(click)` event, how can I make a unique variable that could be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(click)="{{collapse+i}}={{!collapse+i}}"
```

should be

```
(click)="this[collapse+i] = !this[collapse+i]"
```

This allows you to use an indexer to obtain the field on the component. If it actually works depends on how you have `collapse` fields defined on your component.

---

Personally I would prefer extending the type contained in the `workQueues` array with an additional field.

```
(click)="queue.collapsed = !queue.collapsed"

...

<tr *ngIf="queue.collapsed">
```

---

An other alternative is to define a new field in the `*ngFor`.

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let queue of workQueues; let i = index; let isCollapsed = true">
<tr>
  <td><button (click)="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed">{{queue.WorkQueueName}}</button></td>
  <td *ngFor="let role of roles">
    <input type="checkbox" />
  </td>
</tr>
<tr *ngIf="!isCollapsed">
  Yay...
</tr>
</ng-container>
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vmamga)

Comment: Let me give this a try real quick.  Did not know about indexers in Typescript/javascript, but I do know of them in C#

Comment: This still expands all hidden rows, as with my first code block posted.

Comment: @monstertjie_za - like I said, it is hard to say if it works because I do not know the code in the component. Personally I would prefer options 2 or 3 that I included in the answer.

Comment: 3rd option produces: Cannot assign to a reference or variable!  Think safest will be option two.

Comment: @monstertjie_za - See this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vmamga) for a working demo of option 3.

Comment: Check myne: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-79kvcs?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Works in Stackblits, but not in my application, and I literally copied the html over

Comment: @monstertjie_za - check that the casing and spelling is the same in your app. Accidentally creating a "new" variable with a mis-type is a common error that is difficult to catch and can easily duplicate that behavior. [Example stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-u96bex) <= Here I "accidentally" defined it as `let sh0wItm = false` with a zero.

Comment: Thank for your assistance.  I eventually decided to use the second approach.