# Custom Directive -- Parser Error: Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected

Tags: angular

I've created a custom directive `appFade`, and am trying to add it to a child component as below. When doing so, I get "Parser Error: Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected." The culprit is: `[appFade]="{{true}}"`. I saw on [Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42456459/got-interpolation-where-expression-was-expected) that:

`{{}} never goes together with [prop]="..." or (event)="..."`

I tried getting rid of the interpolation and/or the `[ ]` and many other permutations, but nothing works so far. Any ideas how I should fix my code?

Custom Directive "appFade":

```
import { Directive, Renderer, ElementRef, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
import { NgModuleResolver } from '@angular/compiler';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appFade]'
})
export class FadeDirective {

  constructor(private renderer : Renderer, private el : ElementRef) {
    el.nativeElement.style.opacity= '.6';
    el.nativeElement.style.transition = '.4s opacity'
   }

  @HostListener('mouseover') mouseover() {
    this.renderer.setElementStyle(this.el.nativeElement, 'opacity', '1');
  }

  @HostListener('mouseout') mouseout() {
    this.renderer.setElementStyle(this.el.nativeElement, 'opacity', '.6');
  }
}
```

HTML file:

```
  <app-repository-display [searchResults]="searchResults.repositories" [appFade]="{{true}}"></app-repository-display>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use `appFade fade="true"`  in the markup and then create an  `@Input() fade: boolean;`   in your  @directive class to receive this value.   If your goal is to just add a fade parameter to your component then you should configure it there as input and not define a custom directive.

Comment: Thank you! That worked great. Also realized that if I want it always to work, I don't even need the fade="true". appFade, alone, worked.

Comment: true.  but in essence you could bind that one to something like `[fade]="toggleFadeState"`  this is where the binding comes in.

Comment: Many thanks. Curious why fade="true" in your initial response, but [fade] with "[ ]" (square brackets) in [fade]="toggleFadeState". I'm trying to learn definitively when the "square brackets" are needed, and when not needed. Tks!